# Is Redaction in Google Cloud DLP reversible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I can't find info on Google Doc's that mentioned it. I found this that says:

> If you want to simply remove sensitive data from your input content,
> Cloud DLP supports a redaction transformation (RedactConfig in the DLP
> API).

Source: [Google Doc](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference)

Does *remove* mean delete and irreversible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Redaction deletes the part of the data that is specified to remove and it is not reversible.**

Choosing the  de-identification transformation depends on the data you want to de-identify and the purpose of de-identifying the data.

Cloud DLP supports some de-identification techniques and in that

[Redaction](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference#redaction) is used to delete all or part of a detected sensitive value.If you want to simply remove sensitive data from the input, Cloud DLP supports a redaction transformation (RedactConfig in the DLP API).

**`redactConfig`**

Specifying [redactConfig](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.deidentifyTemplates#redactconfig) redacts a given value by removing it completely. The redactConfig message has no arguments; specifying it enables its transformation.

**Crypto-based tokenization** encrypts the original sensitive data  using a cryptographic key. Cloud DLP supports several types of tokenization, including transformations that can be reversed, or "re-identified."

Reversible transformations can be reversed to re-identify the sensitive data using the [content.reidentify](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/reidentify) method.

Refer to the link for more information on [Crypto-based tokenization](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference#crypto).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud DLP supports a redaction transformation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud DLP does support a collection of reversible anonymization techniques.

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/transformations-reference

See the column "Can Reverse"